# Php 3 roll dice probability calculation

Tags: php

I am trying to write a php code to give me possible range of values of rolling 3 dices, each dice as we know could be a range from {1 - 6}

so here is what I have :

```
 $x = rand(1,6);
 $y = rand(1,6);
 $z = rand(1,6);
```

so the output would be ;

```
 $a = $x + $y + $z;
```

I am trying to write a php function to determine probability of $a ; the Low output which is 3 ( 1 + 1 + 1) & the max is 18 which is (6 + 6 + 6) How could I do that?

Thanks

Comment: *each dice as we know could be a range from {1 - 6}* some one needs to play some D&D

Comment: you want to calculate the probability of every potential roll? because the range is obvious without having to do any fancy coding: 3 -> 18, aka (1+1+1) -> (6+6+6)

Comment: `$numDice = 3; $low = 1; $high = 6; function diceRange($numDice, $low, $high) { return array('low' => $numDice * $low, 'high' => $numDice * $high); } print_r(diceRange($numDice, $low, $high));`

Comment: yes the probablity of each potential combo roll

Comment: Then edit your question because nowhere in it does it ever mention probability.

Comment: And now that you've edited your question, [this article seems to address how to calculate probability](http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Multiple-Dice-Probabilities). See if you can program that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm bored:

```
$sides=6; 
$num=3;

function diceRange($sides,$num) { 
  return array('low' => 1 * $num, 'high' => $sides * $num); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific please. The range of any set of dice with any amount of numbers or just the range of that particular set. Or the range after a certain amount of rolls?

For a specific amount of rolls see below

```
$min = 0;
$max = 0;

for ($roll = 0; $roll<$amountOfRolls; $roll++){
  $a = $x + $y + $z;
  if ($a<$min){
    $min = $a
  }

if ($a>$max){
    $max = $a
  }

}

$range = $max-$min;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the total of each possible roll, determine the frequency that each total comes up, and therefore the probability.  Then extend this technique for different kinds/combinations of dice rolls.  Here's an example using 3d6:

```
$totals = array();

$count = 0;
for ($x = 1 ; $x <= 6 ; $x++) {
    for ($y = 1 ; $y <= 6 ; $y++) {
        for ($z = 1 ; $z <= 6 ; $z++) {
            $total = $x + $y + $z;
            if (isset($totals[$total])) {
                $totals[$total]++;
            } else {
                $totals[$total] = 1;
            }
            $count++;
        }
    }
}

foreach ($totals as $num => $freq) {
    $probability = number_format(100*$freq/$count,2);
    echo "$num: $freq ($probability %)\n";
}
```

Here's a website which includes different types of dice in different combinations - specifically for D&D: http://rumkin.com/reference/dnd/diestats.php